# When Ansible initiates a PowerShell script, how to get Ansible to return "ok" (nothing changed)?

Tags: powershell, ansible

Usually when Ansible kicks off a PowerShell script with `win_command`/`win_shell`/`win_psexec`, as long as it doesn't run into errors it'll return "changed", because of course it doesn't know what all the script did.

Since we can return any exit code in a PowerShell script is there a way, via exit codes or otherwise, to notify Ansible that there was no change required so that Ansible returns an "ok" status? Or will it always return "changed" no matter what (assuming no failure)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found it. The [win_powershell](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_powershell_module.html) module accesses the `$Ansible` PowerShell variable, whereby I can modify what information is returned to the controller.

From the [win_powershell](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_powershell_module.html#note) documentation:

- `$Ansible.Result` is a value that is returned back to the controller as
  is.
- `$Ansible.Diff` was added in the 1.12.0 release of ansible.windows and
  is a dictionary that is set to the diff result that can be
  interepreted by Ansible.
- `$Ansible.Changed` can be set to true or false to reflect whether the
  module made a change or not. By default this is set to true.
- `$Ansible.Failed` can be set to true if the script wants to return the
  failure back to the controller.
- `$Ansible.Tmpdir` is the path to a temporary directory to use as a
  scratch location that is cleaned up after the module has finished.
- `$Ansible.Verbosity` reveals Ansible’s verbosity level for this play.
  Allows the script to set VerbosePreference/DebugPreference based on
  verbosity. Added in 1.9.0.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell as a pseudo code example, based on your rc variation scenario where we could imagine you exit with `0` when nothing changed, with `4` when something changed and with any other code when something went wrong...

```yaml
- name: some shell task
  ansible.windows.win_command: my_command
  register: my_command
  failed_when: my_command.rc | int not in [0,4]
  changed_when: my_command.rc | int == 4
```

For more information, see [Error handling in playbooks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html)

Note that for commands which are strictly informational and never change anything, `changed_when: false` is perfectly acceptable.